# When is it advantageous to use curly braces for dereferencing in Perl?

Tags: perl

I saw a bit of code that went like this~

```
my @array = @{ $array_ref };
```

And I found that it works just the same if I change it to~

```
my @array = @$array_ref;
```

Likewise, this~

```
my %hash = (frogs => sub {print "Frogs\n"});
&{$hash{frogs}}();
```

Works just the same as~

```
%hash = (frogs => sub {print "Frogs\n"});
$hash{frogs}();
```

(Although I initially tried that as `&hash{frogs}();` expecting it to work, with a resulting error I did not understand-- shouldn't the sigil correspond to the thing being accessed in the hash, in this case `&` for a subroutine?)

So I am wondering why the authors of these snippets would have written them the other way, when it's extra characters without any advantage that I can perceive.

Is something going on here which I'm not noticing? When might there be a situation where you *need* to use the curly braces instead of just the sigil?

Comment: When you use [`perlcritic` and Perl Best Practices](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::References::ProhibitDoubleSigils)

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: Note that `%{}` and `@{}` are sometimes referred to as the "circumfix operators".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are conflating two concepts.

The first thing you need to learn is that there is there are [two syntaxes](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408) for deferencing.

```
 Circumfix            Postfix
 "Block syntax"       "Arrow syntax"

 $BLOCK               EXPR->$*
 @BLOCK               EXPR->@*
 $BLOCK[$i]           EXPR->[$i]
 &BLOCK()             EXPR->()
 ...                  ...
```

Furthermore, both syntax have a simplification available to them.

---

Your array example is an example of a simplification available to the block syntax. If the block contains nothing but a simple scalar (`$ref`), you can omit the curlies.

```
${ $ref }                   # Can be simplified to $$ref
@{ $ref }                   # Can be simplified to @$ref
${ $ref }[$i]               # Can be simplified to $$ref[$i]
&{ $ref }()                 # Can be simplified to &$ref()
```

If the block contains anything else, you can't avail yourself of this simplification.

```
@{ $refs{$key} }            # Can't be simplified
@{ f() }                    # Can't be simplified
@{ my $ref = f(); $ref }    # Can't be simplified

&{ $refs{$key} }()          # Can't be simplified
&{ f() }()                  # Can't be simplified
&{ my $ref = f(); $ref }    # Can't be simplified
```

---

Your code ref example, on the other hand, is an example of the switching from the block syntax to the arrow syntax. It's not a simplification *per se*.

```
"Block syntax"               "Arrow syntax"
&{ $hash{frogs} }()    ⇒     $hash{frogs}->()
```

---

Your code ref example is also an example of a simplification available to the arrow syntax. When the arrow is between `[...]` or `{...}`, and `[...]`, `{...}` or `(...)`, the arrow can be omitted.

```
$ref->{$k}->[$i]            # Can be simplified to $ref->{$k}[$i]
$ref->{$k}->{$l}            # Can be simplified to $ref->{$k}{$l}
$ref->{$k}->()              # Can be simplified to $ref->{$k}()

$ref->[$i]->[$j]            # Can be simplified to $ref->[$i][$j]
$ref->[$i]->{$k}            # Can be simplified to $ref->[$i]{$k}
$ref->[$i]->()              # Can be simplified to $ref->[$i]()
```

---

Finally, which should you use?

The choice of whether to the block syntax or the arrow syntax is one of personal preference, but the following conventions are usually followed to maximize readability:

- The block syntax is preferred for scalar, array and hash dereferences.

  ```
  $$ref                is generally preferred over     $ref->$*
  @$ref                is generally preferred over     $ref->@*
  %$ref                is generally preferred over     $ref->%*
  ```
- When using the block syntax, curlies are omitted if possible.

  ```
  $$ref                is generally preferred over     ${ $ref }
  @$ref                is generally preferred over     @{ $ref }
  %$ref                is generally preferred over     %{ $ref }
  ```
- The arrow syntax is preferred for array element, hash element and code dereferences.

  ```
  $ref->[...]          is generally preferred over     $$ref[...]
  $ref->{...}          is generally preferred over     $$ref{...}
  $ref->(...)          is generally preferred over     &$ref(...)
  ```
- The arrow itself is omitted when possible, except when used to deference code.

  ```
  $ref->[...][...]     is generally preferred over     $ref->[...]->[...]
  $ref->[...]{...}     is generally preferred over     $ref->[...]->{...}
  $ref->[...]->(...)   is generally preferred over     $ref->[...](...)
  $ref->{...}[...]     is generally preferred over     $ref->{...}->[...]
  $ref->{...}{...}     is generally preferred over     $ref->{...}->{...}
  $ref->{...}->(...)   is generally preferred over     $ref->{...}(...)
  ```
- The block syntax is preferred for array slices and hash slices. It's far less readable than the arrow syntax, but the arrow syntax for these requires Perl 5.24.

  ```
  @$ref[...]           is generally preferred over     $ref->@[...]
  @$ref{...}           is generally preferred over     $ref->@{...}
  ```

Comment: In my second example, with the hash, isn't that simplified despite consisting of more than a scalar? I don't see the difference between my hash example and your `@{ $refs{$key} } ` example.

Comment: @Aerovistae, No. You didn't simply (omit the curlies), you used an entirely different syntax. There are [two syntax to dereference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408), specifically `&BLOCK()` and `EXPR->()` for code refs, and you switched from the former to the latter. The arrow (`->`) deference syntax is generally thought to be more readable, and while the arrow can be omitted between indexes and between an index and a param list, most people keep it between an index and a param list for readability.

Comment: If you had done the same thing for arrays as you had done for the code ref, you would have used `$array_ref->@*`, not `@$array_ref`

Comment: I understood everything you said, that's very clear, except the asterisk in `$array_ref->@*`. Is that just a stand-in to indicate that something goes there, or is there literally supposed to be an asterisk?

Comment: Literally supposed to be an asterisk.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is ***primarily*** for other people and the compiler/interpreter to read. Junior programmers often tend to treat their creations as being purely for their own consumption, as a sort of living notepad, but there really are much better ways of writing design notes than encoding them in a programming language.

It's about explaining clearly to the (human) reader what your code is doing. Your example of `@$array_ref` (apart from being pointless unless you really need two copies of the same list of data) is fine, but how would you read `$$array_ref{key}`?

Most people don't hold the table of operator precedence in their heads, so it's a lot easier to *explain* your intention by writing either `$array_ref->{key}` or `${ $array_ref{key} }` depending on what you mean

Given that you mention this

```
&{$hash{frogs}}()
```

I think you're reading something that is either rather old, or written by someone who doesn't know Perl especially well. The `&` prefix is required only when you're referring to the subroutine as a first-class data object, such as fetching a reference, and just calling the subroutine isn't one of those

Perl allows you to omit the indirect operator `->` between consecutive pairs of closing and opening brackets, but it's often clearer to include it. I generally omit it between curly and square brackets (indexing hashes or arrays) but keep it in for procedure calls

I would write that line as

```
$hash{frogs}->()
```

Comment: I've purged all the comments here. Be civil, folks.