# how to solve the “Experimental values on scalar is now forbidden” problem in perl

Tags: perl

In Perl 5.26.2 I get:

```
Experimental each on scalar is now forbidden at a.plx line 67.
Type of arg 1 to each must be hash or array (not private variable) at a.plx   
line 67, near "$val)"
Execution of a.plx aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Where line 67 is the while in

```
 67 while (my ($ip, $val2) = each($val))
 68 {
       ......
    }
```

Comment: Also make sure you understand the [caveats with each](https://perldoc.pl/functions/each) which are more fully documented in 5.28. Namely that several operations within your while loop can cause it to break by resetting the `each` iterator, or a previous iteration might remain unfinished. An alternative is iterating with `foreach` through the keys instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`each` takes a hash, not a reference.<sup>[1]</sup> Therefore,

```
while (my ($ip, $val2) = each($val))
```

should be

```
while (my ($ip, $val2) = each(%$val))
```

---

1. Perl 5.12, 5.14 and 5.16 allowed a reference to be used. This was a mistake.

   Perl 5.18, 5.20 and 5.22 still allowed it, but warned if you did.

   Perl 5.24 reverted this addition.

Comment: You could use that, but most people find it's just find it noisier. See the "which should you use?" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060022/589924) (at the bottom).

Comment: I prefer the `for my $key (keys %{$val}) {...}` syntax.