# How can I use Perl's each with a list?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.038;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie ':all';
use Devel::Confess 'color';

while (my ($i, $t) = each('a','b','c')) {
    say "$i, $t";
}
```

but I get an error:

`Experimental each on scalar is now forbidden`

`('a','b','c')` is a scalar?

I really like Perl's `each` on arrays, as I don't have to declare an iterator variable.

I have also tried

`while (my ($i, $t) = each(('a','b','c'))) {`

`while (my ($i, $t) = each(qw('a','b','c'))) {`

but get the same error.

`while (my ($i, $t) = each(@{ ('a','b','c') }) {`

but the above gives an error: `Useless use of a constant ("a") in void context` which I got from [how to solve the “Experimental values on scalar is now forbidden” problem in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761118/how-to-solve-the-experimental-values-on-scalar-is-now-forbidden-problem-in-per)

How can I convince Perl's `each` that ('a','b','c') is an array?

Comment: Nice attempts.  But: 1)  it's `qw(a b c)`, _not_ `qw('a','b','c')`.  See [qw](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qw/STRING/). 2) If you go with `@{...}` then that de-references an arrayref -- so inside has to be an array reference; so `@{[ qw(a b c) ]}` (where `[...]` creates an anonymous array, a reference).  However, this doesn't work either as `each` wants an actual variable (`@`) because of its prototype

Comment: `...as I don't have to declare an iterator variable.` That is what you're doing now. Actually you are declaring two variables

Comment: @TLP I meant an additional variable that wouldn't be local like I have above

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. I suspect you are misunderstanding something.

Comment: Re "*`('a','b','c')` is a scalar?*", `('a','b','c')` is an expression that produces either a scalar or three depending on context.

Comment: @TLP I think that what they meant is that they are trying to avoid `my $i = 0; for my $t (@arr) { ...; $i++ }` by doing `for (my ($i, $t) = each @arr) { ... }`, which is totally reasonable. "as I don't have to declare an iterator variable" should probably have been "as I don't have to declare an iterator variable _in an outer scope_".

Comment: @dada That is still just a messed up way to get indexes from an array, and each does not fix that. The idiomatic way would be to loop over the indexes if you need them, and get the value from the array itself. There's no need for a global variable. This is an XY-problem.

Comment: @TLP I disagree. It can be useful to have both the index and element, and `each ARRAY` is precisely designed for this. Also, OP wasn't suggesting to use a global variable: they said "it wouldn't be local", but I'm pretty sure they meant "it would in an outer scope", not "it would be global".

Comment: @dada I am not arguing semantics or whether each is a useful function, I am just saying that the premise that each does not require an iterator variable is a flawed one. You don't have to use an extra iterator variable for any loop control structure. And if the OP thinks so, s/he might need to study those topics further

Comment: @TLP I think that the 8733 persons that upvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522578/4990392) (which shows the Python equivalent of `each`) would disagree. Also, why in general you don't _need_ an extra iterator, there are certainly cases where it's nice to have.

Comment: @Dada "I think 8733 persons would disagree". With what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I convince Perl's each that ('a','b','c') is an array?

You can't, because `('a','b','c')` is just a list of string literals (scalars).  It is not an array variable.

Docs for [each](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each) are clear

> each HASH
>
> each ARRAY
> ...

So it wants a variable, either a hash or an array.

---

There is also the question of the error that comes up

> but I get an error:
>
> `Experimental each on scalar is now forbidden`
>
> `('a','b','c')` is a scalar?

First off, the full error message that I get for such code

```
perl -wE'while( my ($i, $t) = each(qw(a b c)) ) { say "$i, $t" }'
```

is instructive

```
Experimental each on scalar is now forbidden at -e line 1.
Type of arg 1 to each must be hash or array (not list) at -e line 1, near "qw(a b c)) "
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The function `each` is [prototyped](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Prototypes),

```
perl -wE'say prototype "CORE::each"'  #-->  \[%@]
```

so it needs one item which need be a hash or an array variable.  By passing it a list we have a mismatch which is caught at compile time, and is fatal.  So right there it's game over.

However, as an additional courtesy we *also* get that message about "*experimental each on scalar*".

If this mismatch in prototype were to pass (not be fatal), the list `'a', 'b', 'c'` would then be an expression to be evaluated, which yields either three scalars or one scalar (by [comma operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Comma-Operator) the first two items are thrown away and the expression returns `'c'`, or, if precedence is the other way round, `'a'` is returned and the rest discarded), depending on context.

In either case a scalar would be intended for `each`, what used to be allowed then warned against then outright forbidden.  Now `each` accepts only a (hash/array) *variable*, not an expression, and in reference to this history we also (still) get an extra message.

Comment: The function is prototyped, `perl -wE'say prototype "CORE::each"'` prints `\[%@]` (on v5.32) and so it wants _variables_.  It may be possible (?) to build and give it an array right there but doing that would be a true atrocity, far outweighing an inelegance of declaring an array.

Comment: I'd be curious to see how it's possible. I haven't been able to do it: it doesn't work with a dereferenced anonymous array as it creates it anew every time, so it doesn't iterate past the first element.

Comment: @choroba  Yeah, same here; that's why all the hedging (may, ?) ... dunno how to create an array _and_ give `each` the variable, inline.  Whatever I make on the fly (arrayref, `do` block) gets evaluated into a list when I try to "pass" it.  (I even sinned with string `eval` and stayed with a fruitless sin...)

Comment: @ikegami Thank you, I had added a fat footnote (before seeing your message, for which I didn't get notification?). How does one know it'd be scalar context? The prototype `\[%@]` bails out already on having a list, so I figured the "experimental scalar" part of the error message is a 'what if'.

Comment: Re "*How does one know it'd be scalar context?*", Operators don't actually use prototypes. It's not really `\[%@]`. It accepted a reference for a while, which is a scalar. So anything there would have been evaluated as a scalar. But the context is kinda moot. So not mentioning it is good.

Comment: @ikegami "_Operators don't actually use prototypes. It's not really `\[%@]`_ -- heh, OK, thank you.  That's one thing I never fully resolved, when a thing's an operator or a "function."  How does one tell?  (From sources?)  Then, I suppose the main difference is in how they're parsed...?  I've looked around the docs as i was writing this and saw it (`each`) specifically called "function" in multiple places, and decided that then this is a "function."  But then of course that's a regular go-to term, and the thing is used as a function so it's easy to call it that.

Comment: Re "*How does one tell?*", They're all operators. "The functions in this section can serve as terms in an expression. They fall into two major categories: list operators and named unary operators." Not entirely true, as there's also nullary `time` and whatever `map` and `grep` are, but note that it calls them all operators. `perl -MO=Concise` also shows them as operators (though `map` and `grep` result in two operators each, IIRC).

Answer (score 2):

`('a','b','c')` is not an array; it is a list.  Refer to [each](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each).

If you assign the list to an array variable, it will work:

```
my @array = ('a','b','c');
while (my ($i, $t) = each(@array)) {
    say "$i, $t";
}
```

Output:

```
0, a
1, b
2, c
```